# How to deploy a JavaScript automation app?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, deployment, webautomation

I have built a web automation programme with selemium & javascript. Now i want make it usable for everyone so that anyone can use it without any dependecies or coding environment i mean any non technical people can use it easily.
**how can i do it?**

Comment: Can you please define "make it usable for everyone" - do you want people to execute your scripts? Create their own? What about the destination OS? - can you please share details of what you're trying to achieve and what you're stuck on?

Comment: Right now if anyone want to execute my script they have to install few more supporting stuff and configure them. I want to make it like other software, just install & ready to work. And my destination os is windows.

Comment: does this help? https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg   it helps create an exe from a js -  keeping in mind you'll probably hen need add it all to a zip or self extracting executable - you'll need to include (at least) your webdriver exe (i.e.gecko or chromedriver)   let me know if it's good and i'll make an answer out of it :-)

Comment: Seems this will meet my requirement

Comment: i'll throw an answer together :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use: https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg

> This command line interface enables you to package your Node.js
> project into an executable that can be run even on devices without
> Node.js installed.

The most useful part will be dependencies:

> During packaging process pkg parses your sources, detects calls to
> require, traverses the dependencies of your project and includes them
> into executable

However, i expect this will not manage the webdriver executable. You'll most likely need to ship chromedriver/geckodriver/etc with your resultant exe.

Looking forward, i expect you'll need to manage your distributable for the rollout of new browser versions. Different users will be on different versions at different times and your relevant drivers will need to be updated and re-shipped.